# Tensorflow and Bert What are they exactly and what's the difference between them?

Tags: nlp, tensorflow2.x

I'm interested in NLP and I come up with Tensorflow and Bert, both seem to be from Google and both seem to be the best thing for Sentiment Analysis as of today but I don't understand what are they exactly and what is the difference between them... Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Tensorflow* is an open-source library for machine learning that will let you build a deep learning model/architecture. But the [*BERT*](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-bert/) is one of the architectures itself. You can build many models using *TensorFlow* including *RNN*, *LSTM*, and even the *BERT*. The transformers like the *BERT* are a good choice if you just want to deploy a model on your data and you don't care about the deep learning field itself. For this purpose, I recommended the [*HuggingFace*](https://huggingface.co) library that provides a straightforward way to employ a transformer model in just a few lines of code. But if you want to take a deeper look at these models, I will suggest you to learns about the well-known deep learning architectures for text data like *RNN*, *LSTM*, *CNN*, etc., and try to implement them using an ML library like [*Tensorflow*](https://www.tensorflow.org) or [*PyTorch*](https://pytorch.org).

Answer (score 1):

> Bert and Tensorflow is not different thing , There are not only 2, but many implementations of BERT. Most are basically equivalent.

The implementations that you mentioned are:

The original code by Google, in Tensorflow. https://github.com/google-research/bert
Implementation by Huggingface, in Pytorch and Tensorflow, that reproduces the same results as the original implementation and uses the same checkpoints as the original BERT article. https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
These are the differences regarding different aspects:

In terms of results, there is no difference in using one or the other, as they both use the same checkpoints (same weights) and their results have been checked to be equal.
In terms of reusability, HuggingFace library is probably more reusable, as it is designed specifically for that. Also, it gives you the freedom of choosing TensorFlow or Pytorch as deep learning framework.
In terms of performance, they should be the same.
In terms of community support (e.g. asking questions in github or stackoverflow about them), HuggingFace library is better suited, as there are a lot of people using it.
Apart from BERT, the transformers library by HuggingFace has implementations for lots of models: OpenAI GPT-2, RoBERTa, ELECTRA, ...